# Questions regarding "stuttering issues", are they really appropriate for Arqade?

Tags: discussion

So I found a random question that was bountied a while ago asking for help with stuttering issues that the user are having:

[Why is my game stuttering?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/318616/why-is-my-game-stuttering)

My question is: Are these really answerable on a site like *Arqade*? My concern is that the questions will only go downhill with people posting up their full specs for a problem that can be as simple as "your computer is overheating", or "your drivers are out of date" or dreadfully "lower your game graphics sessions" and anything like that.

I understand [technical-issues] when it comes to an issue with that particular with a game. Same Mass Effect's AMD graphical bug (play on AMD GPU on the later stages and you'll find that the game is unplayable because it is literally too dark... the fix: go to the console and brighten it synthetically instead).. But is something that is more or less PC hardware related able to be asked to here?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to tech support.  It doesn't work very well in a Q&A format, as it requires a lot of back and forth to really determine what's going on.

That said, we still allow questions about tech support, but only when it's specifically an issue with the game itself.  We apply the tech support acid test to these questions:

> Remove the game from the question.  Does the problem still exist?  Then it likely doesn't belong here.

This also applies to things we determine are in our wheelhouse, such as Steam, Origin, or the like.  It ensures that questions we deal with are actually gaming issues; problems with the games themselves, instead of things that might look like a gaming problem, but is actually a problem outside the game.

So as long as we can determine the problem is with the game itself, we can help.